# Unable to add video youtube url in product page as also got error The preview image information is unavailable. Check your connection and try again

Tags: magento2, catalog, product-video

Unable to add video youtube url in product page as also got error
**The preview image information is unavailable. Check your connection and try again.**

[image]

I am using magento 2.4.4-p1 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurred, due to unable to get the remote image of youtube link. so check the youtube link or curl request is not completed as check the curl request have all access privilege .

```
$image = $this->curl->read();
    if (empty($image)) {
        throw new LocalizedException(
            __('The preview image information is unavailable. Check your connection and try again.')
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks . It’s worked for me . Issue with you network access.

Answer (score 2):

If a given message/LocalizedException showing in the admin product edit page area then it fails in the following situations.

- `remote image` source found empty, not available from a source(Youtube/Vimeo).
- cURL request timeout here `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl::read`

Comment: Thanks, curl is working but issue with network and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**1 - Obtain a YouTube API key**

```
Visit the
```

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=magento2-342010

- Select ‘YouTube Data API v3’
  [image]
- Select ‘Enable’
  [image]
- Select ‘Create Credentials’ > ‘API Key’
  [image]

  Copy the text which displays your unique API key

**2 - Adding your YouTube API key in Magento 2**

- On the sidebar of Magento go to Stores > Settings > Configuration
- Under ‘Catalog’ select ‘Catalog’
- Under the ‘Product Videos’ area,
- paste your previously copied YouTube API key                  into
  the required field
- Save

  [image]

**3 - Adding a YouTube video to a Magento 2 product page**

- Now to tell Magento to insert the video on to a Product page…
- Visit the product page edit view you wish to add the video to
- Go to the ‘Images and Videos’ section
- Click ‘Add Video’
- Enter the URL of the video you wish to embed
- Click the ‘Get Video information’ button to fill in a lot of the
  details and customise as required
- Save your product
  [image]

**All that is left is to check the frontend of the website to ensure your video has appeared.**

**Remember to clear your cache under ‘Cache Management’ for good measure if you find the video is not yet visible.**

**see the result in frontend**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kind of your current using theme xml layout error.

Possible to check `catalog_product_view.xml` from the custom theme and using the reference instead copying all xml content from parent theme.